# What to do with leftover almond peel?

Tags: culinary-uses, nuts, almonds

I always soak almonds at night and peel them the next morning. I'm just wondering if I can do anything with the leftover almond skin. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just eat the entire almond?

Comment: @Catija : if you're making almond milk, this is a common thing to do, as you don't want the flecks of brown bits.

Comment: Not really a culinary use, but they'd make a fine mulch material for an herb garden?

Comment: I suggest you simply add them to your compost bin.

Comment: @Catija almond skin have bitter taste as it contain enzymes that protect the almond from spoiling, Also it contain  Phytic acid that lower the ability to digest iron and calcium.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY  Apparently there are thoughts that actually almond skins may have healthful properties: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6523744/

Answer (score 10):

I made bacon  Mixed together 2 tablespoons oil,  3 tbs soy sauce or tamari, 2 tbs nutritional yeast, 1 tbs woostershire, 1/2 tbs maple syrup, 3/4 tbs hot paprika in a bowl.  Mix in 3 cups loose Almond skins.  Bake 375 for approx 20 minutes on non stick surface until crispy.  BLT waiting to happen.  Or use as bacon bits on salad...
[image]

Comment: I just made them and was wondering how they would do as they cooled.  I am in a humid climate and they are crispier now then when they came out of the oven.  They would even be good by themselves as a snack:)

Comment: That's a neat idea! Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Don't forget to take the [tour] and to browse our [help] to learn more about the site and the SE system in general. With this answer you have gained even enough rep to meet other users in [chat].

Comment: I made these last night and they are very yummy.  I left out the worcestershire and maple syrup.  They don't really taste like bacon, but are a fun slightly crunchy snack.

Comment: I tried this with my own ingredients (similar, but -wostershire and +tomato paste and +garlic powder).  Note: they cook quickly and mine started to burn.  10 min at 175C was too much.  So, just watch them!

Answer (score 3):

They're really thin, so it's a really small amount of food. I wouldn't feel at all guilty about pitching them, but if you do want to use them, that means the main way it'll really matter is if you use them for texture or appearance.

But usually we do the opposite: remove the skins from nuts to make something with a smooth texture and uniform color. So I don't have a lot of really exciting suggestions in that department. I suppose you could grind them up a bit and mix them into something that you want to look speckled, probably baked goods?

If you *don't* want that look or texture in anything though, just don't use them. Sure, you could grind them up fine and put them in something that's got its own color so you can't see them, but they won't really be adding much of anything at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use them in baking cookies, cupcakes,or you can even dry them, grind them and then add in yoghurt or condensed milk or ice cream.

You can even use them to cleanse your skin by simply grinding and mixing with your daily face wash.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Nutrition is off-topic here, and the OP didn't really ask anyway. They just asked what to do with them; seems there's no need to convince them to use them.